# Cannot find module 'server.io'

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

i just try to run the commend in terminal to run the node js server , in this scenario i type node app.js in my terminal. I don't know what went wrong ..

throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'server.io'

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/socket/app.js:4:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)

var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = require('server.io').listen(server);


server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: missing server.io dependency into your package.json ? Forgot npm i ?

Comment: I am new to node js .. please explain it ..
{
  "name": "socket",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.6"
  }
}

Comment: run `npm i server.io --save` then try again. read the doc https://docs.npmjs.com/ https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning https://nodesource.com/blog/semver-tilde-and-caret/

Comment: i try this... it causes this error .. 
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-58-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "server.io" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.7
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/server.io
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'server.io' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

Comment: To explain the above in a bit more detail -- you absolutely need to install node modules before you use them. `npm install --save server.io` is a convenient way to do this and put it in your package.json. Yet, since you're using Express, I'm led to believe that you already know this. I'm not finding a module called server.io... are you sure you don't mean to write socket.io?

Comment: npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/socket/npm-debug.log

Comment: I already install node and npm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package.json snippet in your comment lists `socket.io`, but you're trying to require `server.io` in your app.js. Try changing that to `var io = require('socket.io')(server)`. It doesn't seem like server.io is a thing...

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io for more info.

Comment: Make sure you pay attention to minor naming issues like that before you ask about it here.